# Exibir valor de Select escolhido

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5

Eu tenho essa dropdownlist:

```
 <select>
                <option value="0">Selecione os capitulos</option>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Capitulos)
                {
                    <option value="@item.IdCapitulo">@item.TituloCap</option>
                }

            </select>
```

Como faço para exibir o valor escolhido na mesma página? Quero que o usuário quando escolher o capítulo, automaticamente carregue a escolha do usuário numa textarea abaixo. É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz esse exemplo utilizando jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.capitulos').on('change', function(){
     $('.escolhido').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='capitulos'>
   <option value=''>Selecione...</option>
   <option value='1'>Capítulo 1</option>
   <option value='2'>Capítulo 2</option>   
</select>

<textarea class='escolhido'></textarea>
```